# How to fail master Jenkins pipeline job if downstream jobs fails

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration

I have a Jenkins pipeline `master` job that triggers 2 jobs `buildjob1` and `buildjob2`.

My `master` pipeline job is simple like this:

```
   stage ("Test") {


                build (job: buildJob1,
                             parameters: [
                                    string(name: 'A', value: "AA),
                                    string(name: 'B', value: "BB),

                             ],
                             propagate: false)


              build (job: buildJob2,
                       parameters: [
                           string(name: 'A', value: "AA"),
                      ],
                     propagate: false)


        }


    cleanWs()
}
```

I want both the downstream jobs to run and mark the master job unstable/failed if any of the jobs fail.
How do i do that through pipeline?

Comment: if the job fails you can just add a `sh'exit 1'`

Answer (score 1):

In case the jobs dont rely on each other, use parallel with the FailFast parameter - and you have to remove the propagate option (or set it to true)

```
stage ("Test") {
    parallel buildJob1: {
        build (job: buildJob1,
            parameters: [
                string(name: 'A', value: "AA),
                string(name: 'B', value: "BB),
            ])
    }, buildJob2: {
        build (job: buildJob2,
            parameters: [
                string(name: 'A', value: "AA"),
            ])
    }, failFast: false
    }

cleanWs()
}
```

Edit: As you commented, that the Jobs can only run sequential, we have to manually inspect the job result and set the pipeline-job result by hand. This way, we can call as many sequential Jobs, as we like:

```
stage("buildjob1") {
    result = build (job: buildJob1,
        parameters: [
            string(name: 'A', value: "AA),
            string(name: 'B', value: "BB),
        ], propagate=false)
    // Inspect result
    if(result == 'FAILURE') {
        echo "buildjob1 failed"
        currentBuild.result = 'UNSTABLE' // of FAILURE
    }
}
stage("buildjob2") {
    result = build (job: buildJob2,
        parameters: [
            string(name: 'A', value: "AA"),
        ], propagate=false)
    // Inspect result
    if(result == 'FAILURE') {
        echo "buildjob2 failed"
        currentBuild.result = 'UNSTABLE' // of FAILURE
    }
}
stage("cleanup") {
    // Call your cleanup
    cleanWs()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!!! Parallel seems to cause some stability issues. So we can run them only sequentially

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap this stage inside a try catch, if have any error ==> make the current build status to `FAILURE`

```
try {
    stage("Test") {
      build (job: buildJob1,
             parameters: [
               string(name: 'A', value: "AA"),
               string(name: 'B', value: "BB"),
             ],
             propagate: false)
      build (job: buildJob2,
             parameters: [
               string(name: 'A', value: "AA"),
               string(name: 'B', value: "BB"),
             ],
             propagate: false)
    }
} catch (error) {
    currentBuild.result='FAILURE'
}
```

Comment: But this would still not execute buildJob2, in case buildJob1 did not complete, or would it?

Comment: if buildJob1 has failure (error, cannot complete), it means the main stage will be stopped immediately because of buildJob1, no need to care about buildJob2 then (break by above failure event, not be triggered)

Comment: But that is, what the user asked for.